Microsoft Graph Service Client fails to PATCH Custom Security Attributes
According to the official Microsoft documentation, one can assign custom security attribute values using the following code:
var requestBody = new User
{
    CustomSecurityAttributes = new CustomSecurityAttributeValue
    {
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {
                "Engineering" , new 
                {
                    OdataType = "#Microsoft.DirectoryServices.CustomSecurityAttributeValue",
                    ProjectDate = "2022-10-01",
                }
            },
        },
    },
};

var result = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].PatchAsync(requestBody);

This is apparently the C# equivalent of the following HTTP PATCH request:
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}
Content-type: application/json

{
    "customSecurityAttributes":
    {
        "Engineering":
        {
            "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.DirectoryServices.CustomSecurityAttributeValue",
            "ProjectDate":"2022-10-01"
        }
    }
}

Whilst I have successfully utilised the Graph Explorer and run an HTTP PATCH request for custom security attributes without incident, my C# code does not work. Instead, the client throws the following error:
Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: Invalid property 'SalesforceAccountId'.
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.ThrowIfFailedResponse(HttpResponseMessage response, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, Activity activityForAttributes, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.SendAsync[ModelType](RequestInformation requestInfo, ParsableFactory`1 factory, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.SendAsync[ModelType](RequestInformation requestInfo, ParsableFactory`1 factory, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Users.Item.UserItemRequestBuilder.PatchAsync(User body, Action`1 requestConfiguration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at PwsPortal.App.Services.MsGraph.GraphService.AssignAccountIdToUserAsync(String userId, String accountId) in C:\Users\George\source\repos\PwsPortal2\PwsPortal\App\Services\MsGraph\GraphService.cs:line 90
   at PwsPortal.Controllers.SalesforceController.AddSecurityAttributeToUserAsync() in C:\Users\George\source\repos\PwsPortal2\PwsPortal\Controllers\SalesforceController.cs:line 105
   at lambda_method77(Closure, Object)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

*** Headers omitted ***


However, as you can see, my code is near-enough identical to the Microsoft example - the method is the same, only the set, name, and value, are different:
var requestBody = new User
{
    CustomSecurityAttributes = new CustomSecurityAttributeValue
    {
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {
                "SalesforceAccountId" , new
                {
                    ODataType = "#Microsoft.DirectoryServices.CustomSecurityAttributeValue",
                    Id = accountId,
                }
            },
        },
    },
};
await _graphServiceClient.Users[userId].PatchAsync(requestBody);

My question is; what is going on and how can it be solved? I need to programmatically add custom security attribute values and apparently the graph service client doesn't behave like it is supposed to in this instance. What am I doing wrong?

Could you pls help confirm whether it worked or not when using the sample codes? If the sample codes worked, have you tried to change Id to other property name like AccId?

@TinyWang I have tried the sample - it also does not work with the same error ("Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: Invalid property 'Engineering'."). It doesn't even get to the stage where the service client actually makes the PATCH request - it fails on the method itself.

I have successfully utilised the Graph Explorer and run an HTTP PATCH request for custom security attributes without incident --> can I understand it as you already have correct API permission and your account has correct user role? And you only get issue within SDK? If so, I noticed that in the callstack, there's Microsoft.Graph.Beta looks to be Beta version SDK, could you pls switch to V1.0 version?

@TinyWang Yes, permissions are not an issue as I can use the graph explorer to run the request no issue, I just can't run the request in C# using the Graph Service Client. I switched to v1.0 and it still doesn't work.

sorry I don't have any other ideas then, since I don't have test resouce, I can't test in my side.

This is a confirmed issue with the SDK snippet generator and the way it serialises/deserialises anonymous types.
There is a solution on GitHub as well, but it is messy, unintuitive and probably isn't very robust:
var requestBody = new User
{
    CustomSecurityAttributes = new CustomSecurityAttributeValue
    {
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {
                "Engineering" , new CustomSecurityAttributeValue() // Specify the object rather than using an anonymous type
                {
                    OdataType = "#Microsoft.DirectoryServices.CustomSecurityAttributeValue",
                    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object> { // Put the custom attribute key and value into the AdditionalData property
                        { "projectDate", "2022-10-01" }
                    },
                }
            },
        },
    },
};

Hope this helps if anyone searches for the same problem. This was current as of this date and Graph SDK 5.52.0.
